# Are larger cities typically easier targets for Covert Ops?

Tags: civilization-beyond-earth

In Civ 5 it seems heavily implied that larger cities offer a higher chance of success in [Covert Ops](http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/Covert_Operations_%28CivBE%29) than in smaller cities. But I'm not sure if that still holds true for beyond Earth's revamped intrigue system. I know that some buildings and satellites affect intrigue, but I'm just curious about how size alone affects Covert-ops.

Does the size of a city have an impact on a mission's success or otherwise?

Does the City size affect how easy it is to gain or lose intrigue?

Comment: You always have the most wonderful civ-beyond-earth questions.

Comment: @Chantola - Thanks and thanks for the answers. I'm trying to log my questions as I attempt to perfect my strategy.

Comment: Not an answer because I can't be sure I have all the information. But, I haven't yet seen any reference that directly relates city size to operational success. However, city size does impact the health of a city and poor health increases the chance that a covert operations would succeed. So, the only connection I know of is indirect, and can still be mitigated by virtues, buildings, and a few other things.

Answer (score 1):

Size didn't actually affect intrigue, but it seems like it does because those cites are usually older, so the other empires/colones are more likely to know about them than newer cites, so they will trade and spy on those, rather than newer cites that they may not even know of.